# trying to use XmlTextWriter and format a date time value

Tags: xml, date, format, xmltextwriter

I am trying to convert a row of data from our database values into a xml file.
I am using the c# .net xmlTextWriter.
Everything is fine but I cannot format the date time value for some reason.

Below is the code I have tried using a String.Format:

```
xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Call", namespace);
xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}", man.orderDateTime));   
xmlWrt.WriteEndElement();
```

In the database the value of the date and time is displayed as: 23 Jul 2015 13:05.

Need it to display as 23 Jul 2015 13:05 but it is displaying as Jul 23 2015 1:05PM in the xml that i am out puting for some reason.

Comment: I found the answer and it was a silly one! the datatype on the database is a varchar and it displayed the incorrect date in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it was a silly one! the datatype on the database is a varchar and it displayed the incorrect date in the database.

The syntax above is correct i believe